Physical significance of the net electric field through a gaussian surface not depending on any external charge
Why doesn't gauss law consider the external charges when calculating the electric field at a particular region?
I am not sure where I've gone wrong in the following, so any help would be appreciated:
Here, the net electric field at the point where the dark spot is situated is 0 by coulomb's law. However if I draw a gaussian surface (represented by the red surface), the electric field doesn't take into account the external charge and evaluates to kq/r^2


You can't assume the field is uniform over the Gaussian surface because the charge distribution and the surface don't share the same symmetry. Both the internal and external charge matter when determining whether the field is uniform over the surface due to symmetry.
You could use one Gaussian surface to determine the field contributed by one charge, and another surface to determine the field contributed by the other charge, and then combine them by superposition. But this would be basically the same as using Coulomb's law in this example.
